# Fetching JSON Data from Nominatim API is not working

Tags: javascript, json, geocoding, nominatim

I am working on a project which requires geocoding with the Nominatim API.
Requests like [these](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Germany&format=json&limit=1) work in the browser but they do not work in this fetch() function in JavaScript:

```
fetch('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Germany&format=json&limit=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
```

> Does not work.

Other links to other APIs work though:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
```

> Works.

I am using Node.js v18.12.1 in VS on Fedora 37.

I already tried other ways of writing this fetch() function.

Comment: `await(await fetch('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Germany&format=json&limit=1')).json()` works for me. But I think there is a daily quota of requests that you can make from a given IP address.

Comment: Shoot, that could be the problem. My code requests 500 API calls which may be too many calls.

Comment: I will try to use the fetch() function alone tomorrow.

Comment: I'm just getting "Error: Couldn't connect to server" when I try to make any request to  https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org

I'm wondering if the server is down, maybe permanently, and I missed the memo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Nominatim API seems to have a limit for the number of API requests in a certain time frame.

Not requesting to many requests at once solved my problem.